How do you connect a src module in Melange with it's associated test file that's using Melange-Jest?
I have a Melange project with the following directory structure:
├── src
│   ├── dune
│   ├── App.re
├── __tests__
│   ├── dune
│   ├── App_test.re

The dune files in both the src and __tests__ folders use a melange.emit stanza to compile the directories into javascript during the build. I want my App_test.re file to use the App module defined in App.re, but in order to do so, I need to create a library stanza in the src/dune file that includes the App module, and then declare that library in my melange.emit stanza in the __tests__/dune file. The problem with this is that my melange.emit stanza in my src/dune already includes App as a module, so I'm unable to also declare a library in src/dune that contains the App module. How can I get my App_test.re file to open my App module without throwing the error "Unbound module App"?
I've tried to set this up following the instructions on the Github for melange-jest (the testing framework I'm using) but there's not any documentation specifying how to fix this issue.
Here are the basic contents of my four files:
src/App.re:
[@react.component]
let make = () => {
  // HTML content here
};

__tests__/App_test.re:
open Jest;
open Expect;
open ReactTestingLibrary;
open App; // build throws "Unbound module App" error here

let () =
  describe("Reason Syntax", () => {

    let container = <App></App>;
  });

src/dune:
(melange.emit
 (target output)
 (alias app)
 (libraries reason-react melange.belt)
 (modules :standard)
 (preprocess
  (pps melange.ppx reason-react-ppx))
 (module_systems es6)
 (runtime_deps
  (glob_files_rec assets/*.scss)
  (glob_files_rec assets/*.js)))

__tests__/dune:
(melange.emit
 (target test)
 (alias test)
 (libraries
  reason-react
  pages_tests
  melange-jest.jest
  melange-testing-library.dom
  melange-testing-library.react)
 (preprocess
  (pps melange.ppx)))


Can you not just add app to libraries in the test project?

When I add "app" to the tests/dune file libraries stanza, it throws this error:
Error: Library "app" not found.
I'm guessing because app is not being declared as a library, but only an alias in the melange.emit stanza (which is just telling it to compile into javascript).

Part of the issue is that I can't create a library that includes the App module, and also emit the App module in a melange.emit stanza. That would give me this error:
Error: Module "App" is used in several stanzas:

src/dune:5
src/dune:45
To fix this error, you must specify an explicit "modules" field in every
library, executable, and executables stanzas in this dune file. Note that
each module cannot appear in more than one "modules" field - it must belong
to a single library or executable.


@glennsl do you know of any public github projects that use melange-jest? I'm new to the dune environment and it would be helpful to be able to copy someone else's directory structure and dune files.

I don't unfortunately, I haven't really explored the melange ecosystem very much yet.
